# Vbscript Add new Worksheet doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I create a Delmia Vbscript that export some data into an Excel file. Everytime I run this program it should add a new worksheet into the same Excel file, to adding new value in a separate table. The problem of my code is that everytime except the first time that I run the program the Woorksheet Object is Nothing and the values aren't save in the Excel file.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objGEXCELapp        As Excel.Application
Dim objGEXCELwkBk       As Excel.Workbook
Dim objGEXCELSh         As Excel.Worksheet

Dim strFileName         As String
Dim strNewFilePath      As String

Sub CATMain()

StartEXCEL

Dim i
For i = 0 To body.NumberOfSegments - 1
    Dim segment As SWKSegment
    Set segment = body.GetSegment(i)

        WriteInExcel i + 1, 1, segment.Name
        WriteInExcel i + 1, 2, segment.FullName
        WriteInExcel i + 1, 3, segment.PositionX
        WriteInExcel i + 1, 4, segment.EndPositionX
        WriteInExcel i + 1, 5, segment.PositionY
        WriteInExcel i + 1, 6, segment.EndPositionY
        WriteInExcel i + 1, 7, segment.PositionZ
        WriteInExcel i + 1, 8, segment.EndPositionZ
        WriteInExcel i + 1, 9, segment.Length

   Next

  Dim file
  file = Dir("C:\temp\ExportData.xls")
  If Len(file) = 0 Then
  objGEXCELwkBk.SaveAs strNewFilePath
  Else
objGEXCELwkBk.Save
End If
objGEXCELwkBk.Close
objGEXCELapp.Quit

End Sub
```

Here there is the method for create a new woorksheet

```
Sub StartEXCEL()

Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next
Set objGEXCELapp = GetObject(, "EXCEL.Application")
If Err.number <> 0 Then
 Err.Clear
 Set objGEXCELapp = CreateObject("EXCEL.Application")
End If


objGEXCELapp.Application.Visible = True

Set objGEXCELwkBk = objGEXCELapp.Workbooks.Open(strNewFilePath)
If Err.number <> 0 Then
    Set objGEXCELwkBk = objGEXCELapp.Workbooks.Add
    Err.Clear
End If

objGEXCELwkBk.Worksheets.Add (After = objGEXCELwkBk.Worksheets.Count)
Set objGEXCELSh = objGEXCELwkBk.Worksheets(objGEXCELwkBk.Worksheets.Count)

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not vbscript, it's VBA.  Please edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the code assign a value to strNewPath:

```
Sub CATMain()
   strNewPath = "C:\temp\ExportData.xls"
   Call StartEXCEL
```

Comment: Indeed, my code already assigns the a value to strNewPath, but I wanted to write the code refere to the worksheet. If it can be usefull I'll put all code af the class CatMain.